# What do I do when I lose an undeposited paycheck?

Tags: salary

I accidentally misplaced a paycheck that I hadn't deposited yet. What do I do from here?

Comment: I have added your country as a tag. Questions like these depend on your culture.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Go to HR or Finance (basically whoever generated the check), ask them to cancel payment on the old check and generate a new one for you.

Comment: I did this when it happened to me. I learned that companies should be able to do this for checks issued up to 2 years in the past. (*I believe that is the legal obligation of companies in U.S. - but I am not really familiar with the laws so don't quote me*)

Comment: For what it's worth, I lost a check from a temp agency nearly 8 years ago.  It turns out that the state treasury office has the money and I can claim it at any time.  Speaking of which, I should probably go get my $30...

Comment: @user1234567890abcdef Yes most U.S states have a Unclaimed Property division in their departments of revenue, they handle things of that sort. I recently found out my dad had like $1000 in pay he never claimed/deposited from a company he worked at 10+ years ago.